# Reverse of a Linked List using iteration

Tags: linked-list, reverse

Given a pointer to a linked list, I'm trying to reverse a linked using iteration(not recursive approach) in java. This is my code snippet.

```
   Node reverse(Node head)
   {
        Node cur = head.next;
        Node prev = head;
        Node nxt;
        while(cur!=null){
            nxt = cur.next;
            cur.next = prev;
            prev = cur;
            cur = nxt;
        }
        return prev;
   }
```

But when I run it it gives error-"Time Limit Exceeded". So, there might be an infinite loop somewhere but I can't figure out where. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set next pointer of head node to null. firstnode.next is still pointing to  the second node of given linkedlist which resulted in infinite looping.

```
Node cur = head.next;
Node prev = head;
prev.next = null; // add this
```